# in C++, can you have a case where ouput needs to be printed as ClassInstance.methodOne().methodTwo()

Tags: c++

A C++ program needs to print `s.getCylinderAt(50,50).toString()`

But I am not sure how to structure the program so that output of `getCylinderAt(50,50)` can be given as input to `toString()`

Comment: What problems are you having? Please, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Comment: In the expression `s.getCylinderAt(50,50).toString()` there's no "input". Rather it seems that `s` is an object, which has a `getCylinderAt` member function. This member function in turn return another object, who have a `toString` member function. And the `toString` function probably returns a string of some kind. Would it be easier to understand if the assignment said something like `SomeType o = s.getCylinderAt(...); std::string str = o.toString();` and to print `str`? That's really the same.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt
Thanks for sharing the links!
As a part of R&D on a project I am stuck with finding if C++ can can output in the form of `classObject.classMethod1().classMethod2`

Comment: @soheljapanwala of course it can. Someprogrammerdude told you exactly how it is possible.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking about, but temporary objects that may be returned by one of the functions are destroyed at the end of the full expression, so something like `char c = std::string("foo").substr(1).operator[](0);` and so should be your code...

Comment: If you print with stream functions (`cout`), it is even possible to overload `<<` and print arbitrary objects with no need for `toString`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Thank you! although I am currently not allowed to modify `cout<<s.getCylinderAt(50,50).toString()`, I now understand what to suggest to make it work. The current code will not work for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer to your question without knowing more details, but based on the names, I would assume you have two classes, `S` and `Cylinder`.

To enable the `s.getCylinderAt(50,50).toString()`, you would need something like this:

```cpp
struct Cylinder
{
    std::string toString();
};

struct S
{
    Cylinder getCylinderAt(int, int);
};
```

As long as `s` has a member function called `getCylinderAt` and returns a `Cylinder`, and the `Cylinder` class has a member function called `toString`, then you can use `s.getCylinderAt(50,50).toString()`.